# Deleting a record in javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I need to delete some records related to the current record when it is deactivated. I can get the the event when the record is deactivated but I have looked around for some time on Google and this site for the code to delete records in javascript but I can't find any, though I know there must be some out there.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: This seems more like a server side rule than a client side rule.

Comment: I would be alright with doing this with a plugin, all I would need to know is how to pick up that the record has been deactivated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would be alright with doing this with a plugin, all I would need to know is how to pick up that the record has been deactivated

You can register a plugin on the `SetState` and `SetStateDynamic` messages (recommend the *Pre* event in your scenario). Each of these messages will pass an `EntityMoniker` in the `InputParameters` property bag which refers to the record that is being deactivated.

In your code you will need to:

1. Check that the new state in the SetState request is deactivated (since of course a record can usually be reactivated and you don't want to try deleting things then too, presumably)
2. Pick up the `EntityMoniker` from `IPluginExecutionContext.InputParameters`
3. Run your query to identify and delete related records
4. Exit the plugin to allow the `SetState` transaction to complete

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to delete a record with JavaScript there is a sample on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309549.aspx).

Its a little long winded (its a CRUD example - create, retrieve, update & delete). But it should contain the information you need.

Note there is also an example on that page which doesnt use jQuery (if using jQuery is a problem).

That said I think for this operation would will find it easier to implement, test and maintain with a plugin (so I would go for Greg's answer).

Additionally a plugin will apply in all contexts, e.g. if you deactivate the record in a workflow your JavaScript will not run, but a plugin will.